# How to send result of a function after the loop is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

In a Node/Express server in CoffeeScript, I have the following function :

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, answer) ->
  result = []
  treatServer(url, server, (treatAnswer) ->
    result.push(treatAnswer)
  ) for server in servers
  answer(result)
```

The treatServer method take some times, and the answer is send before the loop is finish. How can I send the result only when the loop is come at an end ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A simple solution is to maintain a local counter. `var count = servers.length`, then inside the callback, `if (--count === 0) answer(result);`

Comment: Have you checked out any async libraries for node?  https://github.com/caolan/async might help.

Comment: Squint: Your tip works, but I prefer the TheHippo's answer style. Aaron : Node provides native async. But thanks.

Comment: You mean incrementing instead of decrementing? Sure, that'll work too. The library @AaronDufour is talking about is for *managing* asynchronous activities. Unless I missed it, NodeJS doesn't provide anything like that.

Comment: @brnrd squint is right.  Its for managing asynchronous tasks - running them in series, parallel, forEach, etc. and it automatically calls the final callback once everything finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy as long as you know the number of servers beforehand:

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, answer) ->
    result = []
    count = 0
    treatServer(url, server, (treatAnswer) ->
        result.push(treatAnswer)
        count++
        answer result if count is servers.length
    ) for server in servers
```

**Edit:** After thinking about it again. In your case this could be solved even easier:

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, answer) ->
    result = []
    treatServer(url, server, (treatAnswer) ->
        result.push treatAnswer
        answer result if result.length is servers.length
    ) for server in servers
```

**Edit 2:** As [squint](/users/1106925/squint) pointed out, that push returns the length of the array:

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, answer) ->
    result = []
    treatServer(url, server, (treatAnswer) ->
        answer result if result.push(treatAnswer) is servers.length
    ) for server in servers
```

If you want to maintain readability of the code, the last edit might not be the best choice ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much. Haven't thought of this. Won't forget the trick.

Comment: @brnrd There is even a shorter way

Comment: +1 You could even squeeze it down a little more, since `.push()` returns the new `.length`.

Comment: This won't guarantee that the order of the results is the same as the order of the `servers` list, though.

Comment: @TheHippo agreed, just something to realize :)

Comment: I love that last edit for the same reason I love CoffeeScript ! Thanks squint and TheHippo

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/) module

Here is great article [Node.js async in practice: When to use what?](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice) which explains async in details.