# How to convert a function to an async.each function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

I've a small problem with a function in a class of my nodejs/express server.

I have the following function :

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, resolved) ->
  result = []
  treatServer(url, server, (serverObject) ->
    result.push serverObject
    resolved result if result.length is servers.length
  ) for server in servers
```

And since the treat server function can take a wild, and as hinted on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570507/how-to-send-result-of-a-function-after-the-loop-is-finished) of mine, I was considering using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) each for this.

So I'm here :

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, resolved) ->
  result = []
  async.each(servers, treatServer(url, server, (serverObject) ->
    result.push serverObject
        resolved result if result.length is servers.length
  ), (err) ->
    if err 
      console.log next err
  )
```

And I currently get the following error :

```
ReferenceError: server is not defined
```

The treatServer function needs the url and a server for the servers array.
But I don't know how to get this server instance for each one of them, and pass it to the treatServer function.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks already.

**Update:** I'm slightly disappointed as I have no gain at all using async. The function I used takes approximatively 6500ms and the async one is the same. I guess the each function from coffeescript does its job really well.

**Update:** After further tests, I'm finding out that the function is slower with async. Really wierd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) instead: it gathers the results of all operations and passes them as an array to the final callback. It also maintains the order of the input array, which `async.each` doesn't (but that might not be an issue).

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, resolved) ->
  async.map(servers, (server, callback) ->
    treatServer(url, server, (serverObject) ->
      callback null, serverObject
    )
  , (err, result) ->
    if err 
      console.log next err
    resolved err, result // see text
  )
```

Since my CF isn't that great, a JS version too:

```
function resolveServers(url, servers, resolved) {
  async.map(servers, function(server, callback) {
    treatServer(url, server, function(serverObject) {
      callback(null, serverObject);
    });
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    resolved(err, result);
  });
}
```

I would also suggest following the common Node idiom for asynchronous callbacks, where the first argument is an error object (or `null` is no errors occurred), and the second argument the result value. That way, you can propagate your errors all the way back the calling chain.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator function of [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) takes two parameters like this:

```
async.each(openFiles, 
  function(file, callback) {
    // do something with file
    callback()
  }, function(err){
    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

in your case you get a server and a callback, so I would rewrite to something like this:

```
@resolveServers = (url, servers, resolved) ->
  result = []
  async.each(servers, (server, callback) ->
    treatServer(url, server, (serverObject) ->
      result.push serverObject
      resolved result if result.length is servers.length
      callback()
    )  
  , (err) ->
    if err 
      console.log next err
  )
```